# Pandas DataFrame.index.name is deleted by DataFrame.index.date

Tags: python, indexing, pandas

I am new to pandas and also still quite new to python so please bear with me. Here is the question:

I read some data from excel, including some dates. I use these dates as indexes and they are in the form `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. But I need these indices in the form `%Y-%m-%d`. So I wrote

```
df.index = df.index.date # where df is a DataFrame object
```

I found out that after this `df.index.name` is `""`, but it should be `"Date"`. It seems strange to me why the `.name` property should be changed/deleted after the `.date` conversion. I know I can simply put it back as `df.index.name = "Date"`, but is there any kind of explanation for this behaviour or is it a bug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. df.index.date returns an array of datetime.date objects. By stating df.index = df.index.date I override the df.index completely and just assigning values that are datetime.date object, so the name property has to be assigned a new.

Comment: So now that I understand the behavior, the only question that remains is: is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: What are you doing with the index that you need to format it this way? There's the `index.format('%Y-%m-%d')` method, which returns a list of strings. Are you going from higher frequency data to lower frequency? In that case you want to look at `resample`.

Comment: No, I don't want to re-sample data. I want to write my DataFrame object to excel, but the first column should not contain hours, because the hours are added separately as the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you just want to format the dates for output. Because of this, I'd recommend keeping the index as the `DatetimeIndex` and then just format it when writing. The `to_csv()` method has a `date_format` parameter that you can pass a strftime string.

```
In [21]: ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 2), index=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2014-01-01
', periods=20, freq='min'))


In [23]: ts.to_csv('tst.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d')

In [24]: !cat tst.csv
,0,1
2014-01-01,0.23269024172796468,-0.27276285241328363
2014-01-01,-2.1271569576784652,-0.08828528516158064
2014-01-01,-0.7476540707009801,0.4496366704379928
2014-01-01,-1.278025433730537,1.9559942454312738
2014-01-01,-0.5197557973521872,-0.38696497057942586
2014-01-01,1.907212175479462,0.08269395500820262
2014-01-01,-0.002980557062394977,1.649695381207261
2014-01-01,-0.9676320141522591,0.549518266575642
2014-01-01,-1.3499641850605548,-0.11695278340333974
2014-01-01,0.3281427666328896,0.2290718384099928
2014-01-01,0.29854271481529915,-1.606564949527949
2014-01-01,-1.8476324099199142,-1.1062031058677215
2014-01-01,-0.2625937089406767,0.6743539439246344
2014-01-01,0.1901494293074155,2.830381213725509
2014-01-01,-0.16171736635213055,-0.6913561112174935
2014-01-01,-0.6340530961142582,0.1944027320940862
2014-01-01,0.1875828513714546,0.3539781699433568
2014-01-01,1.502398492411021,0.9554844690144768
2014-01-01,0.40825706445611654,-0.6555754482696242
2014-01-01,-1.9870063518613181,0.8300825796678137
```

It doesn't look like `to_excel()` has a date_format option. You could file an issue/feature request on [Github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) if you'd like.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for your answer. I am not familiar with the line !cat tst.csv, but I don't get the result that you got. The date_format option is for datetime objects so the DatetimeIndex object is not formated by it.

Comment: `!cat` is a unix command to display a file. What version of pandas are you using? It looks like the `to_format` option was [added in .13](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/4313) which is technically finished and Windows and will be on PyPI before too long.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the clarification. My version of pandas was .12. When updated to .13 I got the correct result, as the date_format property is applied to all data types in the -13 version of pandas. Thanks for your help once again. Your answer is what I was looking for. Best.

Comment: In pandas .13 date_format property is refered to all datetime object in the index, columns and values. Here is the link http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html